# How to enter the value of one index and column into a new cell with +1 in the iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame named df1:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 50 |
| 10 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |

I would like to create a loop that adds a new column called "Total", which takes the value of col1 index 0 (5) and enters that value under the column "Total" at index 0. The next iteration, will col2 index 1 (4) and that value will go under column "Total" at index 1. This step will continue all columns and rows are completed.

The ideal output will be the following:

df1

| col1 | col2 | col3 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 50 | 5 |
| 10 | 4 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I have the following code but I would like to find a more efficient way of doing this as I have a large DataFrame:

```
df1.iloc[0,3] = df1.iloc[0,0]
df1.iloc[1,3] = df1.iloc[1,1]
df1.iloc[2,3] = df1.iloc[2,2]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has a built in diagonal function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [5, 10, 2], 'col2': [3, 4, 0], 'col3': [50, 3, 1]})
df['Total'] = np.diag(df)

print(df)
```

Output

```
   col1  col2  col3  Total
0     5     3    50      5
1    10     4     3      4
2     2     0     1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `apply` on rows

```py
df['Total'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.iloc[row.name], axis=1)
```

```
   col1  col2  col3  Total
0     5     3    50      5
1    10     4     3      4
2     2     0     1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this logic will help

```
length = len(df1["col1"])
total = pd.Series([df1.iloc[i, i%3] for i in range(length)])

# in i%3, 3 is number of cols(col1, col2, col3)
# add this total Series to df1
```